# How to grep or awk string in non fixed position

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I didn't find similar solution, apart from parsing multiple arguments which is a whole script by it self. 
I need to get handle # from nftables for the script, and having problems because it is not always located on the same position.  With Iptables it was line number which was always listed on the first field so was very easy to capture insert position.
when I do:
`nft -n -a list chain inet fw4 forward`
output would be something like this:

```
table inet fw4 {
    chain forward { # handle 2
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
        ip saddr 192.168.0.0/16 ip daddr 192.168.0.0/16 accept # handle 223
        ct state 0x2,0x4 accept comment "!fw4: Allow forwarded established and related flows" # handle 179
        iifname "br-lan" jump forward_lan comment "!fw4: Handle lan IPv4/IPv6 forward traffic" # handle 180
        iifname "eth0.2" jump forward_wan comment "!fw4: Handle wan IPv4/IPv6 forward traffic" # handle 181
        jump handle_reject # handle 182
    }
}
```

I need to capture "handle #", which in this case is 223 without any spaces before or after
normally I would do:

```
InsNo=$(nft -n -a list chain inet fw4 forward|grep -m 1 "192.168.0.0"|awk '{print $10}')
```

which works only when fixed number of fields are present.  I tried also

```
InsNo=$(nft -n -a list chain inet fw4 forward|grep -m 1 "192.168.0.0"|awk -F'handle ' '{print $2}')
```

which works if no more arguments are present after handle number.  But I'd like to know if there is any more reliable method, in getting this number, also without spaces before or after.

Comment: How about `sed 's/.*\(handle [0-9]+\).*/\1/`?

Comment: Assuming the desired number is always the last space (or tab) delimited string: `awk -v ip="192.168.0.0" '$0~ip {print $NF;exit}'`

Comment: `grep -m 1 "192.168.0.0"` would match `192716839040` - always watch out for regexp metachars like `.` when trying to use literal strings in regexps.

Comment: @January your statement doesn't really do much for me, but listing entire statment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` solutions are your easiest option here (and what you asked about), but a potentially "safer" version can be written with `sed` by matching both `handle` and the consecutive numbers. Just an additional option because... why not.

```sh
nft -n -a list chain inet fw4 forward |
    sed -En '/192\.168\.0\.0/s/.*# +handle +([0-9]+).*/\1/p'
```

---

Final solution was "only first match" and ended up like this:

```sh
nft -n -a list chain inet fw4 forward |
    sed -En '/192\.168\.0\.0/{s/.*# +handle +([0-9]+).*/\1/p; q}
```

The `()` parathesis is a capture group, recovered by `\1` later on, i.e. returning the match within. `[0-9]` matches any digit and the following `+` matches "one or more" of that = any number of consecutive digit(s). Th `p` prints line to stdout. It's needed as we suppress all lines otherwise with the -n flag. To only print one match, simply encapsulate the substitute in `{}` curly brackets and add `q` for quit.

Comment: Thanks @Kaffe.  I like your solution, but can you please give me some explanation of last part  `+([0-9]+).*/\1/p'` of the statement.  will it catch only a handle # number even if some more data is behind handle #?

Comment: and also how to get only 1 match

Comment: Disclaimer: on mobile, so lazy... Anywho, the `()` parathesis is a capture group, recovered by `\1` later on, i.e. Returning the match within. `[0-9]` matches any digit and the following `+` matches "one or more" of that = any number of consecutive digit(s). Th `p` prints line to `stdout`. It's needed as we supress all lines otherwise with the `-n` flag. To only print one match, simply encapsulate the substitute in curly brackets and add `q` for quit, like so:  `sed -En '/192\.168\.0\.0/{s/.*# +handle +([0-9]+).*/\1/p; q}'

Comment: Perfect @Kaffe, Thanks this seems the most efficient option for me, even though I was using `grep` and `awk` originally and there are other solutions using **grep** and **awk** or just **awk**, so I choose this one for solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the line contains `192.168.0.0` and then get a match if the handle part can be anywhere in the line.

After the first match remove the leading `handle`  using substr and exit the program.

For example, if the example data is in `file`

```
awk '
/192\.168\.0\.0/ && match($0, /handle [0-9]+/) {
    print substr($0, RSTART+7)
    exit  
}' file
```

Output

```
223
```

If for exampe the handle part always comes after the ip, you might also use `gnu awk` with a capture group:

```
awk '
match($0, /192\.168\.0\.0.*handle ([0-9]+)/, a) {
    print a[1]
    exit  
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird.   your statement gets handle number but it will also match multiple instances.  I just need the first one.

Comment: @DenisZ The program will exit after the first match

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird. The first one works with 'exit' for first match, but the second statement doesn't match

Answer (score 1):

The piece of information you're apparently missing is that `awk` has a variable named `NF` for the number of fields. And also that you should use the `-F` grep option to interpret the `192.168.0.0` pattern as fixed string, not regular expression.

```sh
InsNo=$(nft -n -a list chain inet fw4 forward | grep -F -m 1 "192.168.0.0" |
  awk '{print $NF}')
```

But piping `grep` in `awk` is usually a waste:

```sh
InsNo=$(nft -n -a list chain inet fw4 forward |
  awk '/192\.168\.0\.0/ {print $NF}')
```

If the field you are interested in is not always the last of the line, but always follows fields `#` and `handle`, and is always a decimal number, we can be a bit more accurate:

```sh
InsNo=$(nft -n -a list chain inet fw4 forward |
  awk '/192\.168\.0\.0/ {
         for(i=1; i<=NF-2; i++)
           if($i=="#" && $(i+1)=="handle" && $(i+2)~/^[0-9]+$/)
             print $(i+2)
       }')
```

And finally, if you want only the first match, just add an `exit` statement after `print`:

```sh
InsNo=$(nft -n -a list chain inet fw4 forward |
  awk '/192\.168\.0\.0/ {
         for(i=1; i<=NF-2; i++)
           if($i=="#" && $(i+1)=="handle" && $(i+2)~/^[0-9]+$/) {
             print $(i+2); exit
           }
       }')
```

Comment: Thanks @Renauld, elegant solution.  I presume only works if handle # is last field. And awk only solution matches all records.  I need just the first one

Comment: With the information you provide it is difficult to guess what is constant and what varies. And I did not find in your question that you want only the first match. If you provide more information we can probably adapt our answers. Please do it by editing your answer, not in comments. Meanwhile, if you want only the first match, just add an `exit` statement: `{print $NF; exit}`.

Comment: Thanks @Renaud I had in my statement grep -m 1 so it's only one match.  Thanks for the update with 'exit' .... simple (when you know) :)

Comment: @DenisZ Ah, yes, `-m 1`. I missed that. Ii would probably be better to clearly state it in the text of your question. Same with the surrounding of the field you want to extract.